# Using Google Maps v2

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, maps

i'm trying to use Google Maps in a fragment, i already did everything that google says and i keep getting this error.

```
11-24 14:00:45.410: E/AndroidRuntime(12483): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

I have the meta-data inside of my AndroidManifest but it keeps saying that i don't have it.

The XML:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</fragment>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:name="com.hylamobi.speakup.fragments.about_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

It's just the map on the top, and some buttons in another fragment.

Comment: Can you post the fragment of your manifest file with the <meta-data> tag ?

Comment: ` <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.andorid.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="AIzaSyCog4vhLoP3bEYAyl7FNqWI8uQPQ5cQB44"/>`

Comment: That should work. Can you post your full manifest to give us more info?

Comment: It's quite big, but i'll try.